# Getting a PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Cache' not found

Tags: magento2, zend-framework

Something went wrong when I was using the Component Manager to install a module, and now I cannot see my front or back ends.

When I try to do anything through the CLI I get this message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Cache' not found in /chroot/home/urbanta1/devm2.urbantactical.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/urbanta1/devm2.urbantactical.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/urbanta1/devm2.urbantactical.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize()
#2 /chroot/home/urbanta1/devm2.urbantactical.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/FrontendPool.php(84): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get('default')
#3 /chroot/home/urbanta1/devm2.urbantactical.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/Config.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool->get('config')
#4 /chroot/home/urbanta1/devm2.urbantactical.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config->_getFr in /chroot/home/urbanta1/devm2.urbantactical.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php on line 148
```

Can anyone tell me what to do? I have looked in the Factory.php, Pool.php etc and I can't tell what is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any custom cache implemented? That might need clearing

Answer (score 0):

Check the code of the module you are trying to install.

I had the same error and it was because i had Magento core files inside one of the vendor modules. So this files were in conflict with the current installation.